# C# KeyPress event method not registering with visual studio? Or code?

Tags: c#, graphics, keypress

when running my game (snake) I am suppose to be able to move the snake around the form using the keys w,a,s and d. (atm I have only written the code for left and right movement just has a jumping off point). However, when running the program nothing happens. I have tried using break points, however, it seems as if my program isn't even reading the keypress method, even though I am pressing keys.

Here is the Move method in the snake class.

```
public void Move(int pixels)
{
    if (pixels < 0)
    {
        xPosition_ = xPosition_ -= SNAKE_WIDTH;
    }
    else if (pixels > 0)
    {
        xPosition_ = xPosition_ += SNAKE_WIDTH;
    }
}
```

And here is the keypress method.

```
private void GameScreen_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 'a')
    {
        snake.Move(-1);
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == 'd')
    {
        snake.Move(1);
    }
    this.Refresh();
}
```

the graphics get drawn fine to the pictureBox control.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the KeyPreview set to true on the form?

Comment: Thanks mate, that did it! Thank you to everyone else who provided assistance as well, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

One possible problem is that your event handler isn't actually connected to the `KeyPress` event. You need to wire up the `KeyPress` event to your event handler in order to make it work; simply naming it `GameScreen_KeyPress` isn't enough. For example, here's how you could do this in the constructor of `GameScreen`:

```
public void GameScreen()
{
    this.KeyPress += new EventHandler(GameScreen_KeyPress);
}
```

Here's an MSDN article on the subject: [How to Consume Events in a Windows Forms Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y0987sc.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this is to override `ProcesCmdKey` for your form, like the example below:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Pressed: " + keyData);
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```